# Holonomic D-module is locally artinian, what about the other implication?

Tags: d-modules

Let $X$ be a complex manifold, and $M$ a coherent $\mathcal{D}_X$-module. Suppose that for all $x\in X$, the stalk $M_x$ is an artinian $\mathcal{D}_{X,x}$-module. Does it follow that $M$ is holonomic?

Comment: I would guess this is not true due to examples (by Stafford, and later Bernstein-Lunts) of non-holonomic simple modules.